# Cannot close silverlight popup with custom control in it

Tags: c#, wpf, class, silverlight, popup

I have a silverlight app with two textboxes. When I focus on one of them, I want my popup with my "virtual" keyboard to show up (works). But, the problem is when I want to close the popup. I want to be able to close it with my "X" button (red color on the screen). How can I do it? I tried everything - delegates, INotifyProperyChanged. Nothing seems to work. In my XAML code you can see that I'm not able to access any of the buttons from MainPage - only from the code of the Custom Control. Here's the problem.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#DB1E1E1E" Margin="0,0,-89,-114">

    <TextBox x:Name="txt1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23"
        Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"
        Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="398" GotFocus="txt1_GotFocus"/>
    <TextBox
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Height="23"
        Margin="10,82,0,0"
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        Text="TextBox"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="398"/>

    <Popup x:Name="popup" IsOpen="True" AllowDrop="True">
        <Grid x:Name="theBack" Background="Black" Margin="80,196,114,24">
            <Keyboard:KeyboardControl x:Name="keyboard" Margin="0,-10,0,10"/>
        </Grid>
    </Popup>

    <Button x:Name="btn"
        Content="Button"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="508,114,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="75"
        Click="btn_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Without Bindings:**

In KeyboardControl.xaml.cs define a custom handler for your control and a method for the click on the close button:

```
public event RoutedEventHandler CloseClick;

private void ButtonX_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (CloseClick != null)
        CloseClick(sender, e);
}
```

Then in KeyboardControl.xaml assign the "Click" event of the "X" button with the method previously created

```
<Button Content="X" Click="ButtonX_Click"/>
```

Then in your MainPage change the layout of KeyboardControl for this:

Finally in MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private void keyboard_CloseClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    popup.IsOpen = false;
}
```